# How to Bind dom element to script data in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add input field onclick some button and that value am trying to bind with some variable in controller. but it is not binding .

How to do?

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app1" >
        <div ng-controller="cont">
            <button ng-click="cal()">try</button>
            <div id="inputid"></div>
            <span>{{val}}</span>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app1',[]);
            app.controller('cont',function($scope){
                $scope.val = "hi";
                $scope.cal=function($compile){
                    var str = '<input type="text" ng-model="val"/>';
                    angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile(str));
                };
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here val value is not changing...

Comment: sry i did mistake...  replace 

angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile(str));    with  

$("#inputid").append(str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were definitely on the right track, using angular element and compile.

Read this for $compile explanation - [Angular - $compile: How it works, How to use it](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html)

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/j06kzjwz/1/)

Code:

```
        var app = angular.module('app1',[]);
        app.controller('cont',function($scope, $compile){
        $scope.val = "hi";
        $scope.cal=function(){
            var str = '<input id="injectedInput" type="text" ng-model="val"/>';
            var el = angular.element(str),
            compiled = $compile(el);
            $('#inputid').append(el);
            compiled($scope);            
        };

        });
```